# UIWebView Evaluating JavaScript

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I run `JavaScript` method on `UIWebView` and expect to get something to `NSString *res`:

```
NSString *jsCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"youtubesearch('%@');",html];
NSString *res = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall];
```

But in `NSString *res` I get an empty string, but when i check the `length` with :

```
int len = searchJson.length;
```

`len` is 150 - the length I expect to get, but the string is empty, any idea what happened in this case?

Comment: Where did the `searchJson` variable came from?

Comment: `searchJson` is totally different thing, what you have pasted here, does not shows that you are using `searchJson`.

Comment: Try your Javascript out using the inspector in Safari on the target page to see what it returns.